# Sockjs > chat-like application in web and mobile app. how to load test the server?

Tags: javascript, testing, chat, sockjs, server-load

Sockjs > I have a chat-like application in mobile and web. I want to do load testing for my server and check its performance.

I have my app and web built in JS.

I need a testing environment where I can execute my JS function many times so that I can test the load on the server.

Comment: you want only `JS` load test environment or  java is also fine?

Comment: JS load test environment...